# Tool to connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have sql developer that I can use to connect to oracle database. But I want to connect to mysql databse. Any free good tool avaialble?

Comment: There is quite good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows

Comment: You can also try SQuirreL if you want auto complete, though I prefer workbench myself.

Comment: If you prefer web tools phpmyadmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php is very good

Comment: [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html) also fits for this purpose. There is a 30 days trial and a free express version. The IDE allows to create and execute queries, develop and debug stored routines, automate database object management, analyze table data via an intuitive interface. This mysql front ent delivers data and schema comparison and synchronization tools, database reporting tools, backup options with scheduling, and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) which has 30-day trial and also [community](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) version. Difference between many free tools and SQLyog are actually SQLyog has many advanced features like Database sync, Schema sync, Import external data, data search etc..
Note that these are available only in Ultimate and Enterprise versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/](http://MySQL%20Workbench) or [http://www.heidisql.com/](http://Heidi%20SQL). Both of them are very good, Workbench is especially good for database schema design.

Answer (score 0):

Download [SQLYog](http://sqlyog.en.softonic.com/download). I am using it for years.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools for this, for example:

- [mySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
- [mySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/)

or, if you want one that can work with other databases too, you could try:

- [Heidi SQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)
- [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)